# Why is docker compose failing with " ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11.6-alpine3.18 "?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker, trying to build a website by following a online course but i was struck with this error in the beginning itself

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13
LABEL maintainer="rohitgajula"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        django-user

ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"

USER django-user
```

Error is

```
[+] Building 1.3s (4/4) FINISHED                                                                                  docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 191B                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 492B                                                                                              0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9-alpine3.13                                                    1.3s
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                     0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9-alpine3.13:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13
   2 |     LABEL maintainer="rohitgajula"
```

I couldn't find solution anywhere.

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem and I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1):

Sure! I'll provide a troubleshooting to help solve the error, even though I couldn't reproduce it, I think the following troubleshooting may help you to find the root cause.

**To troubleshoot the issue:**

1- Check your internet connection to ensure it's stable and working properly.

2- Check your Docker Hub credentials to ensure they are correct and up to date.

3- Verify the image name and tag to ensure they exist and are accurate.

4- If the issue persists, try pulling a different image to see if the problem is specific to this particular image or a general issue with Docker.

So I'll provide a simple Django project I prepared specifically for this issue, this project was running locally and also provided code in a GitHub Repository.

Dockerizing a Django application using Gunicorn is a great way to manage your project and its dependencies in a consistent and isolated environment.

To start, make sure you have Docker and Docker Compose installed on your system. If not, you can install them following the official Docker documentation.

Here's a step-by-step guide to dockerize your Django application using Gunicorn:

**1- Clone the Repository:**

Clone the sample Django application repository available at https://github.com/hugolesta/django-sample.

```
git clone https://github.com/hugolesta/django-sample.git
cd django-sample
```

**2- Update the docker-compose.yaml file to mount the application code and run Gunicorn:**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: app/
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
```

**3- Build and Run the Docker Image**

Build the Docker image using Docker Compose:

```
docker-compose build
```

Run the Docker container:

```
docker-compose up
```

If you prefer using Docker commands directly, you can build and run the Docker image using the following commands:

```
docker build -t my_django_app .
docker run -p 8000:8000 my_django_app
```

**4- Access the Django Application:**

Open your web browser and go to http://localhost:8000 to access the Django application.

How the browser looks like:
[image]

Feel free to modify the Django application according to your project requirements.

For a comprehensive guide and more details, check out the [Django Sample Repository](https://github.com/hugolesta/django-sample). The repository includes a fully functional Django application and a Docker setup using Gunicorn to help you get started.

Happy coding!